# UWP - Validation on ContentDialog's PrimaryButtonClick?

Tags: vb.net, validation, uwp, async-await

My `ContentDialog` is styled like a login form. It verifies password via connection thru SQLite. So in the Primary button's auto-generated `Click` event I have something like below (I made it Async btw):

```
Dim deferral As ContentDialogButtonClickDeferral = args.GetDeferral

If Await conn.Table(Of UserAccount).Where(Function(a) a.Username = UsernameTextBox.Text).CountAsync = 0 Then
    args.Cancel = True
    Dim x As New Windows.UI.Popups.MessageDialog("Username does not exist!")
    Await x.ShowAsync
Else
    'Other conditions
End If

deferral.Complete()
```

Some researching got me to think the `Deferral` is needed for Async situations (to no avail). Currently, with the above code I am getting a **Reflection.TargetInvocationException** on the Await line.

What I want to achieve is display a `MessageDialog` if username does not exist; the `ContentDialog` remaining onscreen for the user to correct himself.

Thanks!

Comment: Which `await` line? Can you post the stack trace?

Comment: @JSteward My bad. The first one, beside the `If`. Also, what do I post on the stack trace? New to this feature. Thanks.

Comment: The inner exception says "The application called an interface that was marshalled for a different thread. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8001010E (RPC_E_WRONG_THREAD))". :(

Comment: I don't think you can show 2 dialogs at the same time in UWP. I mean the first dialog is the actual ContentDialog which is your login form, and the second one is the Error Message Dialog. UWP allows for one popup dialog to be displayed.

Comment: @Rafael I do have a second option of using a `Flyout` :) But I can't seem to get past the validation bit...

Comment: The whole stack trace is best. @Rafael may be on to something but the first `await` throwing points to your SQLite connection are you using any sqlite orm? Can you post details of how you create connecting?

Comment: You mean `conn`? It's on a global class: `New SQLite.SQLiteAsyncConnection("database.db")`

Comment: @AwonDanag can you replace 'UsernameTextBox.Text' in the first await with some hard-coded string and report back? maybe accessing that UIElement is what is causing the problem.

Comment: @Rafael You're on cue; it did work!

Comment: By the way, following @Rafael's suggestion, two dialogs do work, i.e. one on top of another.

Comment: @AwonDanag last time I tried was with 2 MessageDialog , maybe a ContentDialog and message dialog can popup at the same time. thnx for letting me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the "UsernameTextBox.Text" with a hardcoded value and it should work.

Maybe bind the textbox with a TwoWay mode into a variable and then use that variable in that statement.